# SQLAlchemy: how to establish connection before using them?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The first query execution takes much longer than consecutive calls because of connection establishment.

For example:

```
connection_string = '...'
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

first_query = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1').first()  # Takes about 2.2 seconds
same_table_second_query = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1').first()  # Takes about 0.8 seconds
other_table_query = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM Table2').first()  # Takes about 0.8 seconds
```

In my case, the pool is intended to serve multiple threads (and I'll adjust its size accordingly) and performance is VERY critical.

Is there a way to initialize / establish the entire pool before using it? If there's a different solution I'd love to learn it.

---

Edit:
If I use the returned connection instead of the engine:

```
connection = engine.connect()
first_query = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1').first()
same_table_second_query = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1').first()
```

Both take about 0.07s.
But this doesn't solve my problem as I still need an established pool to share between threads.

Comment: Your queries are pulling back _all_ the rows and then throwing away everything except for the first row.  This is very inefficient.  It would be much better if you told the database that you only need one row: `SELECT * FROM Table1 LIMIT 1`

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for pointing that out ! But in my queries this is already the case, I just forgot to put it in the question here.

Comment: Can you try something like `SELECT 1` twice instead to see how much the connection overhead really is?  I can't believe its 1.4 seconds.

Comment: There is something like [pool_pre_ping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.pool_pre_ping) but I don't think it solves this problem because it doesn't ping until you try to use it anyways.

Comment: @IanWilson There's a difference of 0.3s between calls (between my laptop and AWS, not inside AWS). I guess that's the connection overhead? Maybe the main problem is in the queries. I'll look into it. Anyway, 0.3s is still a lot in my case, I still need the connection pool established beforehand.

Comment: @IanWilson if I call the same query twice there really is a drop of about 1.4s. If I call `engine.connect()` and use the returned connection, both run at the same time, which is much lower than what is mentioned in the OP (about 0.07s).

Comment: I suppose you could do something like [this](https://pastebin.com/TanXkT0F), although I'm not sure why you would want to. You will still incur the overhead of opening the connections, you'll just take the hit all at once when the application starts up.

Comment: @GordThompson that's a good solution for my use case, thanks. I guess this also answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to initialize / establish the entire pool before using it?

You could do something like this:

```py
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
conn_list = []
for i in range(engine.pool.size()):
    conn_list.append(engine.connect())

print(engine.pool.status())
# Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 0 Current Checked out connections: 5

for conn in conn_list:
    conn.close()

print(engine.pool.status())
# Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 5 Current Overflow: 0 Current Checked out connections: 0
```

but all it will do is incur the cost of establishing the connections up-front. It also means that you could be creating connections that you may not actually need.